Graph api search not returning the custom metadata columns
I'm using an API to retrieve search results along with item metadata. But I'm encountering an issue where results from a custom column aren't being returned.
I've created a managed property in the search configuration, but it doesn't seem to be working as intended.
Could you please assist me in resolving this?
API: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
Request Body:json data
<!-- language: lang-none -->
{ "requests": [ { "entityTypes": [ "driveItem" ], "query": { "queryString": "Test" }, "fields": [ "title", "path", "ListItemID", "taSPCNumber", "SPCNumber" ] } ] }


I have created a managed property at tenant level search and did the site reindexing. When i am trying to run the query from Postman and graph explorer, custom metadata is not showing.
